# WPF XAML TabItem Header oh right

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to create a template for a XAML WPF application.

I have two problems:

1) I have to set positione TabItem Header on top right of UserControl

2) I set TabItem Style, but when ouse go over tabItem Header, i see default Item effetcs on text.

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="{DynamicResource tab_header_graphic_interface}" Style="{StaticResource generalTabItem}">
      <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Name="scrDrvPan">
      </ScrollViewer>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="{DynamicResource tab_header_list_view}" Style="{StaticResource generalTabItem}">
      <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Name="scrDrvList">
      </ScrollViewer>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

And i set style for TabItem

```
<Grid.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="generalTabItem" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/Font/#Futura Std Medium" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF333333" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 0" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />

    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
      <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
          <!--<DockPanel IsItemsHost="True" LastChildFill="False" Margin="2,2,2,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
          </DockPanel>-->
          <!--<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Property=TabItem.Header}"/>-->
          <TextBlock Background="Transparent" Text="ciao" />
        </DataTemplate>

      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="TabItem.IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/Font/#Futura Std Bold" />
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF333333" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 0" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="TabItem.IsFocused" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/Font/#Futura Std Bold" />
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF333333" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 0" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this in your HeaderTemplate DataTemplate?`

```
<TextBlock Background="Transparent" Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Comment: I tried it ... it not works :-(
I need to apply HorizontalAlignment not on single TabItem Element but on Parent Container of all TabItem....
I do not known so apply this configuration on XAML